# Grep output different with pexpect in freebsd 8.4 and 11.4

Tags: grep, freebsd, pexpect

```
import pexpect
import sys

client=pexpect.spawn("ssh user@ip")
client.logfile=sys.stdout.buffer
client.expect("assword:")
client.sendline(password")
client.expect(">")
client.sendline("shell")
client.expect("#")
client.sendline("ps -aux | grep python > /var/temp.txt")
client.expect("#")
client.sendline("cat /var/temp.txt")
client.expect("#")
```

Pasting the output of the last sendline:
On 8.4:

```
cat /var/temp.txt
root       1558  0.0  0.4 129052 57764  ??  I    18May21   0:07.28 /var/python/bin/python
```

On 11.4:

```
cat /var/temp.txt
```

No output.

This is baffling me. What could be the issue? And do I fix it? (The output is proper if I execute the instructions through SSH session)

Comment: what's your python version? and pexepct?

Comment: You should try `client.sendline("ps -aux > /var/temp.txt")` to find out what `ps` is actually returning.

Comment: @pynexj pexpect(4.8.0 in python2 and python3).

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried that - the output is as expected if grep is not used (both through pexpect and through SSH.

Comment: on my system, python-2.7.16's `sys.stdout` does not have `.buffer`.

Comment: @pynexj sorry about that, that script was for python3. just remove the buffer it should work